# Is there a way to display PRINT results with SQL server JDBC driver?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

If my stored procedure has a print statement inside it:

```
print 'message'
```

Is there a way to fetch the output in java program that connects to SQL Server 2008 through JDBC?

Also, is there a danger that `print` messages left for debugging would shutdown connection when called from JDBC application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44373/5457

```
Statement stmt = ...;
stmt.execute("some sql statement");
SQLWarning warning = stmt.getWarnings();

while (warning != null) {
    System.out.println(warning.getMessage());
    warning = warning.getNextWarning();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattm/archive/2007/09/13/capture-print-messages-from-a-stored-procedure.aspx) shows how to do that in VB.NET

I am sure you can do the same in your java code.

All you need to do is attach a handler function to SqlInfoMessageEvent

VB.NET code specified in the above article does not work properly some how on my studio 2005 environment.

So I re wrote it as below

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()

        'change your database name in following line.
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("server=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;database=Test")



        AddHandler conn.InfoMessage, New SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(AddressOf OnInfoMessage)



        conn.Open()



        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

        cmd.Connection = conn

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.CommandText = "[SPWithPrint]"



        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()



        conn.Close()



        ' Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success



    End Sub



    Private Sub OnInfoMessage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventArgs)

        Dim err As SqlError
        For Each err In args.Errors
            Console.WriteLine("The {0} has received a severity {1}, state {2} error number {3}\n" & _
      "on line {4} of procedure {5} on server {6}:\n{7}", _
      err.Source, err.Class, err.State, err.Number, err.LineNumber, _
    err.Procedure, err.Server, err.Message)
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

Other usefull links are as below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0hee08w.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it.  Your options are to use an output parameter from your stored procedure or to do

```
SELECT 'message'
```

which will give you a `ResultSet` you can read in the Java.