# Log "print" inside stored procedure called from JDBI @SqlCall?

Tags: java, sql-server, micronaut, jdbi

I'm using JBDI from a Java Micronaut application to call various stored procedures from a legacy SQL Server database application. I use the `@SqlCall` attribute.

For debugging purpose would be really useful to have the "print" statement inside the stored procedure logged to the Java application log.

Dbeaver is doing something similar in his output tab and I know that there is some "warning" procedure at the JBDC driver level but I don't know to use it with JDBI.

Comment: The output from print statements are effectively warnings with a 0 severity. Given JDBI layers on top of JDBC, have you tried to walk through the classes to [PreparedStatement.getWarnings()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getWarnings--)?

Comment: It's kinda of a mess, cause warning could also be bound to ResultSets.

Comment: The trick can be done by using .setSqlLogger(new SqlLogger() { and implementing the logAfterExecution method and using getWarnings on  the statement) 

Now the problem is I get the some messages but not all of them, I suppose what @siggemannen was lamenting.  When I have a better solution I will try to post an answer

Comment: @maborg, yeah, the exact correct order of fetching warnings vs getUpdateCount vs hasNextResult is a black box (actually, i suspect that m$ jdbc driver doesn't handle it correctly either, because i have never been able to re-implement ssms warning order exactly in java)

Comment: Also, i think you should execute Statement.clearWarnings after you're done with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this incomplete solution, overriding JDBI SqlLogger .

I get only the first "print" and I'm using the ugly *rSql.contains("CALL ")* to find only stored procedure call.

Probably I'm not fully understanding the internals workings of the SQL-server driver

```java
@Factory
public class JdbiFactory {
    @Inject
    DataSource dataSource;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JdbiFactory.class);

    @Bean
    @Singleton
    public Jdbi jdbi(ResourceResolver resourceResolver) {
        return Jdbi.create(dataSource)
            .installPlugin(new SqlObjectPlugin())
            .setSqlLogger(new SqlLogger() {
            @Override
            public void logAfterExecution(StatementContext context) {
                try {
                    var rSql = context.getRenderedSql();
                    LOG.debug("RenderedSql: [{}] ", rSql);
                    if (rSql.contains("CALL ")) {
                        // get warnings
                        final var warningSt = context.getStatement().getWarnings();
                        logThrowables(warningSt);
                        context.getStatement().clearWarnings();
                        // get warnings on results
                        do {
                            ResultSet resultSet = context.getStatement().getResultSet();
                            if (resultSet != null) {
                                final var warningRs = resultSet.getWarnings();
                                logThrowables(warningRs);
                                resultSet.clearWarnings();
                            }
                        } while ( context.getStatement().getMoreResults());
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    LOG.error("Inside logAfterExecution error ", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SqlLogger.super.logAfterExecution(context);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void logThrowables(SQLException warning) {
        var iterator = warning.iterator();
        do {
            Throwable next = iterator.next();
            LOG.info("Print: [{}]", next.getMessage());
        }while(iterator.hasNext());

    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need `getNextWarning` to handle multiple info messasges. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759801/is-there-a-way-to-display-print-results-with-sql-server-jdbc-driver

Comment: @DanGuzman my first version was using getNextWarning but I was still getting only one message :/

Comment: don't see that you cleared any warnings from statement...

Comment: @siggemannen I have added the clear warnings but I still see only the first print.
probably I should try to understand how the driver work by looking at the code.... 

https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/17625f26f0fdd3db0d67fbb964563e684d876bb4/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerStatement.java#L1270